# How to properly filter two lists that are related by id field in Flutter? And how to put it in widget navigation? Not search bar

Tags: flutter, dart, filter

I am trying to implement filtering two lists using the id of the element. I have 2 screens. On the first screen: a list by category: drinks, desserts, hot dishes, and on the second screen: items that belong to these categories. In the documentation and in other projects, I saw that the id is simply passed to the constructor. However, this does not work for me: on the second screen, the entire unfiltered list is also displayed.

*[I put screenshots for better explanation what I mean. The fisrt screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Up2ce.png)*
[the second screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jcKNO.png)

I tried to implement the `where()` method, passing it in the parameter: FoodSel `(ttId: food.where ((element) => element.ttId == 'ttId'). ToList ()`, but everything is also returned as a list.

*Just a note: it seemes like other solutions explain how to sort or filter by id's inside the one specific array, but i need to sort each element by it's id and display it sorted things on the screen.*

How to properly filter the values ​​and pass the already filtered values ​​to the screen? I have already tried everything including the `contains ()` and `where ()` methods together but ir didn't work.

I was thinking about implementing bubble sorting, but I just can't figure out how to correctly pass what is sorted to the constructor. (And is it even needed here?)

I would be grateful for your help.

First screen:

```
сlass FoodT extends StatelessWidget {
  List <Food> food = <Food>[
    Food(ttId: 1, ttTitle: 'Напитки'),
    Food(ttId: 2, ttTitle: 'Десерты'),
    Food(ttId: 3, ttTitle: 'Горячее'),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(itemCount: food.length,
          itemBuilder: (builder, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(food[index].ttTitle),
          subtitle: Text(food[index].ttId.toString()),
          onTap: (){
            Navigator.push(
                context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => FoodSel(ttId: food[index].ttId)));
```

the second screen

```
List<FoodSelected> marsh = <FoodSelected>[
    FoodSelected(ttId: 1, mrTitle: "Капучино",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 2, mrTitle: "Чизкейк",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 3, mrTitle: "Мясной стейк",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 1, mrTitle: "Американо",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 2, mrTitle: "Круассан",),
    FoodSelected(ttId: 3, mrTitle: "Рыбный стейк",),
  ];
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: ListView.builder(itemCount: marsh.length,
              itemBuilder: (builder, index){
                return ListTile(
                  title: Text(marsh[index].mrTitle),
                  subtitle: Text(marsh[index].ttId.toString()),
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `firstWhere` instead of `where`: `FoodSel(ttId: food.firstWhere((element) => element.ttId == index))`

Comment: Hi :) @Abel Rodríguez. Thanks for your help, but it gives an error "The argument type 'Food' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int'." Should I cast or somethis else?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to call the `ttId` property: `FoodSel(ttId: food.firstWhere((element) => element.ttId == index).ttId)`